# Getting Jackson to return a JSON object from Spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring MVC backend that needs to start handling new URLs that will be hit by client-side jQuery/AJAX calls. These calls are expecting JSON objects to be returned by the server.

I am trying to follow a few examples I was able to find and here's what I have so far:

```
// AjaxResult.java
public class AjaxResult {
    private int answer;
    private String errMsg;

    // Getters/setters for both properties.
}

// Inside MyController.java (a Spring @Controller):
public @ResponseBody AjaxResult handleJQueryCall(@RequestParam("x") String whatever) {
    int ans = calculateSomething(whatever);

    AjaxResult result = new AjaxResult(ans);

    return result;
}
```

I'm not in a position where I can compile/deploy this, but there's *clearly* something missing here...the use of Jackson! So I ask: **how do I specify that the `AjaxResult result` gets returned by Spring, to the client-side, as JSON?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You are missing the mapping :

```
// AjaxResult.java
public class AjaxResult {
    private int answer;
    private String errMsg;

   // Getters/setters for both properties.
}

// Inside MyController.java (a Spring @Controller):
 @RequestMapping( value="/myController", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
 public @ResponseBody AjaxResult handleJQueryCall(@RequestParam("x") String whatever) {
   int ans = calculateSomething(whatever);

AjaxResult result = new AjaxResult(ans);

return result;
}
```